# want to return latest records where results are grouped by

Tags: mysql, aggregate-functions

I'm grouping results by SERIAL_NUMBER and I'd like to display the last records for each group according to record ID DESC this what I've got so far:

```
SELECT * FROM 

 (SELECT `SERIAL_NUMBER`, `PART_NUMBER` , `POSITION` , `DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE` , `DUE_OVERHAUL_DATE`  
  FROM `history_card` ORDER BY `HISTORY_ID` DESC ) AS X  

GROUP BY  `SERIAL_NUMBER`
```

But It does not return the last record, it returns the first one ;(

Comment: why are you using a nested query ? This would do just fine ... SELECT `SERIAL_NUMBER`, `PART_NUMBER` , `POSITION` , `DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE` , `DUE_OVERHAUL_DATE`  
  FROM `history_card` GROUP BY  `SERIAL_NUMBER` ORDER BY `HISTORY_ID` DESC

Comment: Yes, I've just tried it works, but it still gives me , first rows instead of last for each group that's why I was trying to first do subquery to order them by HISTORY_ID desc and then select

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are misusing the heinously confusing nonstandard MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html  (This extension is like a talking horse.  We don't wonder that it works badly. We wonder that it works at all.)

You can get the latest (largest) value of `HISTORY_ID` for each value of `SERIAL_NUMBER` from your table like this:

```
  SELECT MAX(HISTORY_ID) FROM history_card  GROUP BY SERIAL_NUMBER
```

Then you can use that set of `HISTORY_ID` values to retrieve what you want from your table.

```
  SELECT SERIAL_NUMBER, PART_NUMBER, POSITION, DUE_CAP_CHECK_DATE, DUE_OVERHAUL_DATE
    FROM history_card
   WHERE HISTORY_ID 
         IN (SELECT MAX(HISTORY_ID) FROM history_card  GROUP BY SERIAL_NUMBER)
```